# How to test eclipse workspace setup?

Tags: eclipse, ant, build, jenkins, software-quality

I am wondering if it is possible to test the eclipse workspace setup?
E.g. if you have multiple projects, like
EAR (enterprise app)

- WAR1 (dyn. web project)
- WAR2 (dyn. web project)
- WAR3 (dyn. web project)
- UtilJar1
- UtilJar2
- EJB1
- EJB2
- ...

It is very odd to ensure that all changes will work on the local IDE. For the build system itself you can easily integrate it into Jenkins or any other CI. But how can I integrate eclipse to be tested also if changes of developer will not break the local build for an developer?
E.g. are there eclipse ant tasks (or a API), which can be integrated into a build, so we could run eclipse also in a CI?

Or are other ways to ensure that the local build will run same as the build on jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

There's an (now defunct?) project called [ant4eclipse](http://ant4eclipse.org/) for running Eclipse builds from Ant, but they focused on plugin projects and I'm not sure if this helps with EAR projects.

The only way I know of is to use Maven or Gradle with the respective Eclipse plugin, so that your CI and your Eclipse build files are the same.
But this means switching to another build tool, which may not be an option (and has other drawbacks).

A different approach: Commit the Eclipse project files under a different name to your version control system, i.e. `eclipse.project` and `eclipse.classpath` and provide an ant target that copies them to the proper names. Also add an ignore to the version control system for the proper names.
In this way, the developers can do all the changes to their local Eclipse projects that they want, but aren't able to commit them. The "canonical" Eclipse files are only edited by the owner of the build system or the persons owning the sub projects and they are responsible that these canonical files work.

Comment: Ralf, thank you for your answer. Maven is no option for me, I puts me to tight handcuffs onto the way of creating a build. I like the basic idea of using a repeatable system, but maven... So gradle would be nice to use, but we have already invested a lot into the ANT build, so also for now no option. The ant4eclipse looks pretty interessting, but seems really to be defunct :(